# I'm only able to reach my site using www, but not non-www

Tags: apache, dns, no-www, cname

I had a website at `example.com`. I created another website  (`example.hotelrunner.com`) using HotelRunner and changed domains. I did that by changing the `A` records and `CNAME` at Netfirms.

Now `example.com` does not resolve to my new website. Only adding a `www` will allow it to resolve.

I was told that in order to activate my domain on HotelRunner, I need to replace my existing `A` records with the following IP addresses:

```
 - 54.246.128.54
 - 54.246.128.245
```

And also applied the following `CNAME` change:

```
Hostname-www
Value/target-app.hotelrunner.com
```

All I want is to be able to reach my website at `example.com`, I can already access it at  `www.example.com`.

Here is a screenshot of the `CNAME` record at Netfirms:

[image: CNAME]

And here is a screenshot of the `A` record:

[image: A records]

The server type is Apache.

Comment: Did you try to contact your hosting provider? they can fix it very quickly.

Comment: Your domain name should have an A record with an IP address. Your www should be a CNAME pointing www.pereybereapartments.com to pereybereapartments.com. I will have to edit out your domain name from the question to help keep it open for you. I was not able to do a dig and see your DNS records so I cannot give specifics on what is wrong. I would help to know specifically what you changed from -> to. Do the best you can and edit your question so that we can help you.

Comment: Okay. This appears to be a different scenario than the norm. Try creating another CNAME that points your domain name (without www) to app.hotelrunner.com.

Comment: @closetnoc [A records](http://i.imgur.com/fX4F3FP.png) i did like you said .It is not working.

Comment: @closenoc. no ,unfortunately it is not.can you give me some other advice?

Comment: Based upon what I see, this should work- short of a brain malfunction. Can you call your hosting company and ask them for help?? It may be that something on their end needs attention. I did get a page that appears like a 404 from a host. If both records are the same then both should work the same...

Comment: I am not sure if this has anything to do with it, but do you have pereybereapartments.com and www.pereybereapartments.com defined as seen in this page?? http://support.hotelrunner.com/en/knowledge-base/how-to-redirect-domain/

Comment: @closetnoc nevermind the solution you provided earlier works.thank you so much.i just had to be patient.

Comment: Great!! I am so glad. Now you can go make some money. Cheers my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Okay the issue with your configuration here is that the host field should be empty and the points to field should have the IP address in it. An empty host field indicates the domain apex. Put another way your configuration should be...

```
       IN       A      54.246.128.54
       IN       A      54.246.128.245
www    IN     CNAME    target-app.hotelrunner.com
```